# Convert .NET Guid to MongoDB ObjectID

Tags: c#, mongodb, guid

How can I convert a .NET GUID to a MongoDB ObjectID (in C#).  Also, can I convert it back again to the same GUID from the ObjectID?

Comment: In the general case, you cannot convert it back because a GUID has 128-bits, while an ObjectId has only 96-bits. The conversion process is lossy, and therefore not reversible.

Comment: Can I just set the _id for a document to a GUID, and not use the ObjectId at all?

Comment: Norris: (disclaimer I have very little MongoDB experience) I think you can and Mongo won't complain. I think the only reason to pick ObjectId is to save space. This other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125275/mongodb-norm-and-poco might help out.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't convert `ObjectId` into `GUID` and vice versa, because they are two different things(different sizes, algoritms).

You can use any type for mongoDb `_id` including `GUID`.

For example in official c# driver you should specify attribute `[BsonId]`:

```
[BsonId]
public Guid Id {get;set;}

[BsonId]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

[ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs):

> A BSON ObjectID is a 12-byte value
>   consisting of a 4-byte timestamp
>   (seconds since epoch), a 3-byte
>   machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a
>   3-byte counter. Note that the
>   timestamp and counter fields must be
>   stored big endian unlike the rest of
>   BSON. This is because they are
>   compared byte-by-byte and we want to
>   ensure a mostly increasing order.

[GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier):

> The value of a GUID is represented as
>   a 32-character hexadecimal string,
>   such as
>   {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D},
>   and is usually stored as a 128-bit
>   integer

Answer (score 8):

FYI You can convert from an ObjectId to a Guid

```
    public static Guid AsGuid(this ObjectId oid)
    {
        var bytes = oid.ToByteArray().Concat(new byte[] { 5, 5, 5, 5 }).ToArray();
        Guid gid = new Guid(bytes);
        return gid;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Only Use to convert a Guid that was once an ObjectId
    /// </summary>
    public static ObjectId AsObjectId(this Guid gid)
    {
        var bytes = gid.ToByteArray().Take(12).ToArray();
        var oid = new ObjectId(bytes);
        return oid;
    }
```

Comment: when I have converted to Guid to ObjectId and again from ObjectId to the Guid the result is different

Comment: When you convert a Guid to an ObjectId you actually loose data. The above conversions are to be a one way repeatable conversion.

Comment: It could be possible to convert from ObjectId to Guid and back but would take some research. I have not been using ObjectId for the last 4 years so I dont know what changes have been made to the ObjectId Type that would need to change the above code. You should write some tests for the conversion back and forth.

Comment: I would try to convert the ObjectId to a 128bit integer then to a Guid instead of the byte array.

Answer (score 3):

although not a direct answer keep in mind that there is no.requirement that _id be an ObjectID --- only that it be unique.

any valid type can be set for _I'd including an embedded object or a . you should be fine (barring any uniqueness violations) using a GUID for _id; in fact, ObjectID is really just a custom GUID.

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting everything from scratch, you can type your "Id" member as a `Guid` instead of `ObjectId`. That's preferred because then your model doesn't have to reference `MongoDB.Bson`, arguably making it a POCO class no more. You don't even need the `[BsonId]` attribute if you name the member "Id", and it's better not to for the aforementioned reason.

If you're already stuck using `ObjectId` in your POCO classes and--having realized the difficulties--would like to change the type of "Id" (in your class), but are not able to change the type of "_id" (in your data), you can make a custom serializer:

```
public class SafeObjectIdSerializer: ObjectIdSerializer
{
    public SafeObjectIdSerializer() : base() { }

    public override ObjectId Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var bsonReader = context.Reader;

        var bsonType = bsonReader.GetCurrentBsonType();

        switch (bsonType)
        {
            case BsonType.Binary: {

                var value = bsonReader
                        .ReadBinaryData()
                        .AsGuid
                        .ToString()
                        .Replace("-", "")
                        .Substring(0, 24);

                return new ObjectId(value);
            }
        }

        return base.Deserialize(context, args);
    }
}
```

As MiddleTommy mentioned, going from `Guid` to `ObjectId` is lossy, but depending on how you use that field, that may not be a problem. The above uses the first 24 hexadecimal characters and discards the remaining 8. If you're storing random `ObjectId` values and not say, an ObjectId conversion of incrementing ints, you should be fine.

If you want to also start writing `ObjectId` as `Guid`, it doesn't seem to hurt anything to mix "_id" types, as long as you're falling back on `base.Deserialize()`, but I could be wrong and it could matter depending on your implementation. The documentation doesn't say one way or the other. To do that you can add this override to the above class:

```
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, ObjectId value)
    {
        var bsonWriter = context.Writer;
        var guidString = value
            .ToString()
            .Insert(8, "-")
            .Insert(13, "-")
            .Insert(18, "-")
            .Insert(23, "-") + "00000000";
        var asGuid = new Guid(guidString);
        bsonWriter.WriteBinaryData(new BsonBinaryData(asGuid));
    }
```

To make that your global deserializer:

```
public class CustomSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(ObjectId))
        {
            return new SafeObjectIdSerializer();
        }

        //add other custom serializer mappings here

        //to fall back on the default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere where it will only be called once, like your Global.asax `Application_Start()`

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new CustomSerializationProvider());
```