# SQL server to MongoDB GUID import

Tags: c#, mongodb, import, guid, objectid

I am trying to pre-populate a referenced field in a POCO class for MongoDB with a value from SQL Server.

The value in SQL Server I am trying to set: 7EDC170D61A2E111BA4B0050569B0004

And in my POCO class to insert into MongoDB, I have the following:

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.CarId = ObjectId.Parse("7EDC170D61A2E111BA4B0050569B0004");

..
collection.Insert<Employee>(e);
```

The problem is that I am trying to import GUID values from SQL Server but I keep getting either byte array size exceptions or invalid hex string exceptions.

Is there a way I can set the ObjectId property values to an existing GUID value from SQL server?

To make it clearer, I have the following POCO class:

```
public class Employee
    {
       public ObjectId id {get;set;}

       public ObjectId Car {get;set;} //this is the one I would like to set manually with a value from SQL Server
  }
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514111/convert-net-guid-to-mongodb-objectid) SO question says you can't do that, I'd suggest following the advice given there.