# .NET - Conditionally Inject/receive dependency service depending on database type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, .net-7.0

Currently I'm developing a project that needs to be able to persist data in different database types(*Postgres*,*MongoDb*)

With that in mind I've thought about abstracting my repository logic into some interfaces in a way that it doesn't matter for my business logic which database type I'm using. This way I can write a logic without caring how the repository will implement it's logic.

But how do I inject it? I mean, How the classes that have its dependency will receive it?

I mean, imagine that:

- In *Postgres*, I'll use **Guid** as id type
- In *MongoDb* I'll use **ObjectId** as Id type

For just an example purpose I'll add everything In a controller file, will be easy to represent it

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    private readonly IExampleRepository<> _exampleRepository;

    public ExampleController(IExampleRepository<> exampleRepository)
    {
        _exampleRepository = exampleRepository;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
public class ExampleEntity<TId>
{
    public TId? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepositoryWithId<T, in TIdType>
{
    Task<bool> ExistsAsync(TIdType id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    Task<T?> GetByIdAsync(TIdType id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
public interface IExampleRepository<TId> : IRepositoryWithId<ExampleEntity<TId>, TId>
{

}
public class MongoRepository : IExampleRepository<ObjectId>
{
    public Task<bool> ExistsAsync(ObjectId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => Task.FromResult(true);
    public Task<ExampleEntity<ObjectId>?> GetByIdAsync(ObjectId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => Task.FromResult(null as ExampleEntity<ObjectId>);
}
public class PostgresRepository : IExampleRepository<Guid>
{
    public Task<bool> ExistsAsync(ObjectId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => Task.FromResult(true);
    public Task<ExampleEntity<ObjectId>?> GetByIdAsync(ObjectId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => Task.FromResult(null as ExampleEntity<ObjectId>);
}
```

Maybe I didn't know how to search for it, sorry if it's a duplicate question.

Comment: Is the database type determined at app start or at the runtime (i.e. on per request/scope basis)?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with MongoDb, but what's stopping you from using a guid for both? (I don't remember if Mongo will force you to add an ObjectId for your entities, but even if it does, you can still use guid as your key for business purposes, you'll just have to properly index it in your Mongo)

Comment: @GuruStron yes, it's based on a defined condiguration. Depending on the environment que are going to deploy It.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, for sure. I could even work with a string and Just cast It before calling the database. I think I'm making too much of an abstraction here. But I thought would be better ask before giving up the Idea.

Comment: Don't work with strings, that's not a smart idea. However, you can work with a set of entities that contains all properties except the `ObjectId` for PostreSQL, and a set that derives from that and only adds the `ObjectId` for mongo, if you must provide an `ObjectId` property (which, again, I'm not sure you must)

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I inject it?
> yes, it's based on a defined configuration. Depending on the environment que are going to deploy it.

Then it should be easy. Just read the configuration values and register what is needed. For minimal hosting model (default in .NET 7 for web apps) it can look like:

```cs
var dbType = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DbSettings:Type");
switch (dbType)
{
    case "Mongo":
        // deps for MongoRepository
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IExampleRepository<ObjectId>, MongoRepository>();
        break;
    case "PostgreSQL":
    default:
        // deps for PostgresRepository
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IExampleRepository<ObjectId>, PostgresRepository>();
        break;
}
```

Of course it can be improved by moving into some extension method and/or changing how configuration is set up and read.

Comment: Actually how to inject It is not the problem. The problem is how It will be injected into the class. Theorically I would have to have both repository types as nullable in the construtor, then check which one is not null and call the methods

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade no, you shouldn't do that, if you have the same interface then you just register it once and inject a single parameter of it in you class ctor. The class accepting dependency should not care about different implementations, that's the whole point.

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade i.e. the `public ExampleController(IExampleRepository<ObjectId> exampleRepository)` stays the same.

Comment: But the id types are diferent. I mean, one is Guid the other one is ObjectId that's from MongoDb driver

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade 1) they are not in the question 2) I would argue that they should not be in your code - it should be either internal implementation detail for repo or you should use the same type for the id, for example you can use [GUID in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514441/2501279)

Comment: I apologize for that mistake, I was trying to write a simple example to make Thais question I'll edit It. But probably I'll work with the same type o ids.